# Process Scheduling using queues

Tags: multithreading, queue, scheduled-tasks

In first come first served process scheduling explained by the  [article](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/07-scheduling.html)

[image]

Say P1 is executing.And P1 has to wait for  I/O.Then it is sent to the *waiting state* .Since this is non preemptive until the I/O of p1 is completed the other processes don't get executed right?
So once P1 has completed his I/O **is it entered to the end of the queue or to the head?**
If its entered to the end then P3 has to be executed right?
Then doesn't it become preemptive?
Or what it meant by non preemptive is while P1 is waiting for I/O p3 doesn't get executed but it waits for p1 to finish to I/O and come back to the end of the queue.
Can someone please clarify the paragraph

> When the scheduler needs to run a process, it picks the process that
>   is at the head of the queue. The scheduler is non-preemptive. If the
>   process has to block on I/O, it enters the waiting state and the
>   scheduler picks the process from the head of the queue. When I/O is
>   complete and the process is ready to run again, it gets put at the end
>   of the queue.

Comment: The last sentence say that it is entered at the end. Does that answer your question?

Comment: if it gets put at the end then does P3 gets executed even though p1 is not finished

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "does P3 gets executed".

Comment: Since p1 has to wait for i/O it goes to the waiting state.Then does p3 move forward in  the queue and the processor start executing it while P1 is still waiting for I/O?After P1 has obtained I/O then it moves back to the queue and all this time p3 and the rest of the processes queued behind p3 will get a chance to execute.Is this what happens ?I thought since this is non preemptive while p1 is waiting for I/O there's no chance for the items now at the head of the queue to be executed because in non preemptive until one task is finished processing the other processes does not get executed?

Comment: "If the process has to block on I/O, it enters the waiting state and the scheduler picks the process from the head of the queue." It's waiting. It is no longer in the ready queue. The head of the ready queue is popped and put into the running state.; Regarding your comment that this could not be possible in a pre-emptive scheduling model: Starting an IO and blocking is a cooperative descheduling operation. The task asks the OS to be descheduled until the IO is done. I actually don't see the difference that being pre-emptive or not makes to this scenario.